# Metabox will not save

Tags: custom-field, metabox

I'm trying to create a metabox in a custom post type. When I attempt to insert information into the Listing Price box and update the post, the information is not saved and disappears once the page reloads. Please take a look at my code below and let me know if you see anything that could be causing this issue. Thanks!

EDIT: I figured it out. I'm still not sure why my previous method wouldn't work. I changed the input field value to ID, 'listing_price', true ); ?> and now the box updates!

```
<?php

function cns_add_custom_metabox(){
    add_meta_box(
        'cns_meta',
        __('ForesTree Listing'),
        'cns_meta_callback',
        'listing',
        'normal',
        'high'
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cns_add_custom_metabox'  );

function cns_meta_callback( $post ){
    wp_nonce_field( basename(__FILE__), 'cns_listing_nonce' );
    $cns_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
    ?>

    <div>
        <div class="meta-row">
            <div class="meta-th">
                <label for="listing-price" class="cns-row-title">Listing Price</label> 
            </div>
            <div class="meta-td">
                <input type="number" name="listing_price" id="listing-price" value="<?php if ( ! empty ( $cns_stored_meta['listing_price'] ) ) { echo esc_attr( $cns_store_meta['listing_price'][0] ); } ?>"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="meta-row">
            <div class="meta-th">
                <span>Listing Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="meta-editor"></div>
        <?php
            $content = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'listing_description', true );
            $editor_id = 'listing_description';
            $settings = array(
                'textarea_rows' => 8,
                'media_buttons' => false
            );

            wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );

        ?>
    </div>

    <?php
}

function cns_meta_save( $post_id ) {
    // Checks save status
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'cns_listing_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'cns_listing_nonce' ], basename(__FILE__) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

    // Exits script depending on save status
    if( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ){
        return;    
    }

    if( isset( $_POST['listing_price'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'listing_price', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'listing_price' ] ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'cns_meta_save' );
```

Comment: Hi, please either add your solution as an answer or select an answer that's closest to your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="number" name="listing_price" id="listing-price" value="<?php if ( ! empty ( $cns_stored_meta['listing_price'] ) ) { echo esc_attr( $cns_store_meta['listing_price'][0] ); } ?>"/>
```

You forget to put "d" where you echo your listing price.

You also not write code for  listing_description for save listing  editor content.

```
if( isset( $_POST['listing_description'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'listing_description', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'listing_description' ] ) );
    }
```

I hope this will help for you.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you are missing your meta name when retrieving the meta value. You just given the post ID, you need to input the meta name too.

```
 $cns_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
```

Should be

```
 $cns_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'listing_price');
```

**Suggestion** 
If you don't want to get the meta in `array` and then parse it with index like `$cns_stored_meta[0]` then you can make the third parameter as `true` which will return the value as string not an array

```
$cns_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'listing_price', true);
```

now you can directly access `$cns_stored_meta`